# Magento 2.2 Moving search into navigation - with code

Tags: php, xml, magento, magento2

I'm trying to move the searchbar into the navigation on Magento 2.2 using a child theme.

Currently, my magento_demo\app\design\frontend\Magento\themename\Magento_Theme\layout\default.xml file contains

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>

    <referenceBlock name="wish-list-link" remove="true" />          <!--for WishList Link-->
    <referenceBlock name="my-account-link" remove="true" />         <!--for My Account Link-->


    <referenceBlock name="logo">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="logo_file" xsi:type="string">images/mytheme-logo.png</argument>
            <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">200</argument>
            <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">200</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

I've done some research and found

```
<move element="top.search" destination="page.top" after="catalog.topnav" />
```

Unfortunately, i'm having no luck with this. If anyone has a good explanation of how this works that would be great, as I will need to move a lot of elements around!

Hopefully someone will understand this, as I've ran out of options to try!

Comment: I've also tried editing topmenu.phtml in \magento_demo\app\design\frontend\Magento\themename\templates\html\ and tried adding a <p> tag, which isn't pulling through?

Comment: I'm not sure your filepaths are correct... `/app/design/frontend/Magento/` would be for the default/base themes, you probably want `/app/design/frontend/YOURTHEME/default` or similar...

Comment: Them filepaths are used to create the theme. so magento_demo\app\design\frontend\Magento\themename contains my theme.xml file, registration.xml file and templates folder.

Answer (score 0):

To move the search bar from header to the colored navigation menu (with category links), you just have to:

1. create a file: `src/app/design/frontend/[Vendor_Name]/[Theme_Name]/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`
2. put this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <!-- Move top.search in navigation menu -->
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="top.search" as="topSearch" template="Magento_Search::form.mini.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="configProvider" xsi:type="object">Magento\Search\ViewModel\ConfigProvider</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

3. then copy: `/src/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/topmenu.phtml` to your theme `src/app/design/frontend/[Vendor_Name]/[Theme_Name]/Magento_Theme/templates/html/topmenu.phtml`
4. in `topmenu.phtml` replace

```php
    <ul data-mage-init='{"menu":{"responsive":true, "expanded":true, "position":{"my":"left top","at":"left bottom"}}}'>
        <?= /* @noEscape */ $_menuHtml?>
        <?= $block->getChildHtml() ?>
    </ul>
```

with

```php
    <ul data-mage-init='{"menu":{"responsive":true, "expanded":true, "position":{"my":"left top","at":"left bottom"}}}'>
        <?= /* @noEscape */ $_menuHtml?>
    </ul>
    <?= $block->getBlockHtml('top.search') ?>
```

5. regenerate static files